# Maximum product of diameter and degree in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be connected simple graph. Let $n$ be the number of its vertices, $D$ be the diameter, $\Delta$ be the maximal vertex degree.

I want to maximize $D\cdot \Delta$ with fixed $n$.

It's relatively simple to put half of vertices into 'star' shape to increase degree and the other half into long 'tail' across one of the rays of the star to increase diameter.

If I calculated correctly that gives $D\cdot \Delta = \left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor\cdot\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil$

Is it possible to do better? And if it is, is it possible to give a universal method to construct such a graph for arbitrary $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the best grade for $D\Delta$.
Let the distance between vertices $u$ and $w$ be $D$ and
$P$ be the shortest path between these vertices.

Let a vertex $v$ be such that $\operatorname{deg}(v)=\Delta$.

If $v$ does not lie in $P$, then
$\operatorname{deg}(v)\leq n-(D+2)+3=n-D+1$,
since at most three vertices from $P$ are adjacent to $v$
otherwise $P$ is not the shortest path between $u$ and $w$.

If $v$ lies in $P$, then $\operatorname{deg}(v)\leq n-(D+1)+2$
since at most two vertices from $P$ are adjacent to $v$ in this case.

In any case $\Delta=\operatorname{deg}(v)\leq n-D+1$. It follows that
$$
D\Delta\leq D(n-D+1)\leq
\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor\cdot\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil.
$$

PS. Thank you, Misha Lavrov. He pointed out the error in the inequalities.

Comment: It's true that $D(n-D+1) \le \left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor\cdot\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil$, but not that $\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}\leq
\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor\cdot\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil$...

Comment: @MishaLavrov You're right.  Corrected.